# What is the meaning of "serves as" in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I read this on a website: "Joker is a 2019 film that serves as an origin story of The Joker."

I don't understand the meaning of the sentence. I searched "serve as(something)" and it means: To act in capacity of a particular role. But it doesn't make sense in the above sentence. and I don't get the point of the sentence.

Comment: What don't you understand about "Joker is a 2019 film that acts in the capacity of an origin story of The Joker."?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey does it just want to say that joker is a film about story of the joker?

Comment: It says that the purpose of 'Joker' is to be an origin story of 'The Joker'. Consider: we did so much shopping at the supermarket that my car served as a freight truck.